# Qt + MSVC 2015 + Firebase SDK v1.0.0

Tags: c++, qt, firebase

I'm trying to build the C++ Firebase sample code found in [Firebase's Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/tree/master/auth/testapp/src) and linking with the libraries of the [Firebase CPP SDK v1.0.0](http://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/cpp/firebase_cpp_sdk_1.0.0.zip) for desktop.
I read the SDK's readme.md and choose the Qt enviroment with MSVC 2015 to build it.
But I got the following errors:

```
libauth.a(credential_stub.o):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in main.obj
libauth.a(credential_stub.o):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj
```

and so on...

How could I build this code for use with Qt or any other C++ compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a QT modules compile with a different visual studio version that the one you are using. See the different compiler versions for the same qt version. For example, you will find that for QT 5.7 the following downloads:

1. Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2015, 918 MB)    (info)
2. Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2015, 924 MB)    (info)
3. Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, 904 MB)    (info)
4. Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, 909 MB)    (info)
5. Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 5.3.0, 1.1 GB)    (info)
6. Qt 5.7.0 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 1.2 GB)    (info)
7. Qt 5.7.0 for WinRT 32-bit (VS 2013, 1.0 GB)    (info)
8. Qt 5.7.0 for WinRT 32-bit (VS 2015, 1.1 GB)    (info)

Jusk  pick the one that match with the compiler you are using.